# Почему выбирает только первую строку из результата

Tags: java, eclipse, h2

```
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TEST");
while (rs.next()) {
    employeeListConnection.add(new Employee(Long.parseLong(rs.getString("ID")),
            rs.getString("NAME"),
            rs.getString("LASTNAME"),
            rs.getString("BIRTHDATE"),
            rs.getString("ROLE"),
            rs.getString("DEPARTMENT"),
            rs.getString("EMAIL")));
    System.out.println(employeeListConnection);
}
```

Выбирает из базы только первую строку. Что может быть не так?

Comment: 1. Строк в таблице `TEST` больше одной? 2. Что такое `employeeListConnection`? Обычный список? 3. Зачем все остальные `rs.getString`, если их значения нигде не сохраняются? 4. Как вы определяете что берётся только первая строка?

Comment: Я бы для начала посоветовал проверить в консоли (терминале), есть ли в базе данных вообще еще строки. Потому что из написанного понять это тяжело.

Comment: @Regent там все rs.getString используются при добавлении объекта Employe. Присмотритесь внимательно.

Comment: @ЕвгенийТупиков да, действительно. Лишнее напоминание о том, что не нужно кучу операций в одну строку толкать.

Comment: Покажите результат запроса "SELECT * FROM TEST" на прямую к серверу БД. И напечатайте resultSet в консоль, так же по полям (или по номерам столбцов).